# How do I get the default bucket name in Firebase, from inside Node.js?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to avoid hard coding the default bucket name in a Firebase project. How do I get it on server side?

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const defaultBucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const defaultBucketName = ...?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get bucket name:

```
const defaultBucketName = defaultBucket.name;
```

Ref: [Interface: ObjectMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.storage.ObjectMetadata#name)

Comment: Thanks, this works. However I think there is nothing in the reference you gave that tells me this should work. Or am I missing something?